# Difference a dataframe from another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe under the name "alltweets" and it has the columns "user_id, username, id, tweet".
I have another dataframe under the name "offensive_users" and it has the columns "user_id, username".
I want to delete rows from "alltweets" when "alltweets.userid" and "alltweets.username" exist in "offensive_users" rows.
How do I do that?